# Как сделать колесо круглым?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
//Использование графики кузова  
        [Embed(source="assets/cabin.png")]
        private var Cabin:Class;
//Использование графики колеса   
        [Embed(source="assets/wheel.png")]
        private var Wheel:Class;
...
//Объединение - машина    
            car = new Compound();
//решение через импорт графического изображения колеса в Bitmap
//Колесо переднее
            wheel_front = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC);
//Установка формы колеса(и материала)
            wheel_front.shapes.add(new Circle(Cars.WHEEL_RADIUS, null, Material.rubber()));
//Центрирование, для того чтобы было координаты (0, 0) совпадали с центром массы 
            //wheel_front.align();
//Присвоение графики для колеса
            var wheel_frontIso:BitmapDataIso = new BitmapDataIso((new Wheel()).bitmapData, 0x80);
            wheel_front = IsoBody.run(wheel_frontIso, wheel_frontIso.bounds);
//Задание начальных координат
            wheel_front.position.setxy(290, 106);
            graphicF = wheel_frontIso.graphic();
//Добавление графического представления колеса в список отображения(на экран)
            addChild(graphicF);
            wheel_front.userData.graphicF = graphicF;
            wheel_front.compound = car;

/*
//или решение через импорт графического изображения колеса в спрайт wheel_front.userData.sprite
            wheel_front = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC);
            wheel_front.shapes.add(new Circle(Cars.WHEEL_RADIUS));
            var wheel_frontIso:BitmapDataIso = new BitmapDataIso((new Wheel()).bitmapData, 0x80);
            wheel_front = IsoBody.run(wheel_frontIso, wheel_frontIso.bounds);
            wheel_front.position.setxy(290, 106);
            graphicF = wheel_frontIso.graphic();
            wheel_front.userData.sprite = new Sprite();
            wheel_front.userData.sprite.addChild(graphicF);
            addChild(wheel_front.userData.sprite);
            wheel_front.userData.graphicF = graphicF;
            wheel_front.compound = car;
*/
```

В обоих вариантах колесо получается многоугольником и машина прыгает. Как сделать колесо круглым? Нужно использовать physics editor или я что-то неправильно сделал и есть вариант попроще?

Answer (score 1):

После просеивания 3 дней сети(в которой одно старьё), и видоизменения всех взаимосвязей, я заметил полигон (как основную причину). правильный ответ(уважаемые знатоки):

при создании колеса обращаясь из основного класса через:

```
 wheel_front = IsoBody.run(wheel_frontIso, wheel_frontIso.bounds, false);
```

к IsoBody.as создаём условие для полигона или круга:

```
    if(isPoligon) 


 body.shapes.add(new Polygon(q)); 
 else 


body.shapes.add(new Circle(Cars.WHEEL_RADIUS,new Vec2(Cars.WHEEL_RADIUS, Cars.WHEEL_RADIUS)));
```

Comment: Ну нет у нас пока знатоков AS3.  Можете стать первым.

Comment: Я не знаю почему Вам налепили минусов, и почему никто не ответил(может нет знатоков по as3?). Но сообщество новое и Вы можете в нём так же участвовать, помогая людям и ставя плюсы, вместо минусов. Зато сами нашли ответ на вопрос - что может быть приятнее?

Comment: незнаю что это значит но минусовать наверно незачем, лучше вместо показать где протупил, наверно..

Comment: Лучше. Но некоторые предпочитают молча ставить минус и с этим ничего не сделаешь - таков принцип SO, что этого, что зарубежного.

Comment: @ixSci: лучше молча ставить минусы, чем отвечать за других! От меня был минус за то, что вопрос состоял из трех предложений типа - 1)колесо не так. 2)что это?  3)ну не так. Вот чтобы Вы поставили за такое? Если не верите можете самую первую версию почитать. Ну а после редактирования вопрос уже не поднимается, как я понял, да и после первой версии отвечать уже не особо хочется.

Comment: @shatal, лично я против молчаливых минусов, т.е. против самих минусов я ничего не имею, но желательно комментировать их, чтобы человек мог исправить. А то ему лепят минусы, а он не понимает за что. Следовательно не может исправиться. Замкнутый круг.